# Get a list of files of mimeType SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm successfully creating files in drive using my drive app and mimeType : 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk'.  As per the readtime-tasks example, I can do realtime collaboration on a file, and also see these files listed in Drive.

However, from my app, I'm unable to get a list of only the files created by my app.

```
 gapi.client.request({
                'path' : '/drive/v2/files',
                'method' : 'GET',
                'params' : {
                    q : "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk'"
                }
            }).execute(onComplete);
```

I'm using the following scopes:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install`

Many thanks.

Comment: don't know why that query fails. Try it in https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it to confirm. By definition, because you only have drive.file scope, your app is blocked form seeing files it didn't create, so a simple files.list q:trashed=false should return "a list of only the files created by my app"

Comment: Thanks.  As a workaround, I've moved my app specific files into appfolder, and used a custom mimetype.

Comment: Small correction on @pinoyyid statement. File scope allows your app to see items it created, as well as items the user explicitly opened with your app (eg, via Right-click 'Open With' in the Drive UI) in you had also specified mime Types/extensions that your app worked with.

Comment: Dan is correct. In fact for completeness, drive.file also seems to allow access to public files that have been shared with you, and files that you have explicitly shared with your app.

Answer (score 1):

The key "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk" is used to create shortcut files, but the eventual MIME Type is specific to your app.  Use the [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it) "try it" to see what the specific MIME type actually is.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to tell what your mime-type actually is. [I have discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28133734/4275251) that `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk` is actually promoted into application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.APP_ID (the first part of your CLIENT-ID) by the google utils.